Не импортируется изображение через props
<div className="news_cards__container">
            {news_cards_data.map((news_card) => (
                <News_card
                    key={news_card.id}
                    title={news_card.title}
                    date={news_card.date}
                    description={news_card.description}
                    image={news_card.image}
                />
            ))}
</div>

<article className="news-card">
            <img
                src={props.image}
                alt={props.title}
                className="news-card__image"
            />
            <h2 className="news-card__title">{props.title}</h2>
            <div className="news-card-description__container">
                <p className="news-card-date">{props.date}</p>
                <p className="news-card__description">{props.description}</p>
            </div>
</article>

Но изображение на странице не отображается
Путь пробовал как-то менять, изображение перетащил в папку с компонентом, чтобы проверить правильность пути. Вроде все верно. Пример объекта, который передается:
{
        id: 14,
        title: "Запуск мобильного приложения",
        date: "07.02.20",
        description: `С сегоднешнего наш сервис стал еще удобнее благодаря приложениям для iOS и Android.
Приложение актуально для действующих, зарегистрированых клиентов. Для подключение ваших камер, оставите заявку. 
Так же вы можете воспользоватся демо кабинетом, для оценки сервиса и приложений. Для этого просто свяжитесь с нами.
Фунционал приложения:  1. Воспроизведение назад в режиме архива. 2. Быстрая перемотка в +/- 10 сек. по двойному нажатию по экрану`,
        image: "./news_image.png",
    },


Согласно преведенного кода, всё инпортируеться. Просто вы указываете не правильный путь к нахождению файла. Заменить image: "./news_image.png",
на image: "https://static1.colliderimages.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2023/10/rick-and-morty-over-the-adult-swim-logo.jpg",

Так у меня изображение лежит в той же папке, что и сам компонент. Зачем мне использовать url ссылку?

@Матвей, значит тебе нужно такие изображения сначала импортировать import image from "./news_image.png", а потом использовать.

Поместите news_image.png туда, где у Вас раздается статика сервером (так как на странице браузер будет смотреть пути относительно сервера страницы, а не того, где лежит изображение в папках проекта)
Либо же нужно сделать импорт изображения с учетом того, что Ваша сборка поддерживает загрузку изображений через импорты
